# Notification Auto Cancel at a Particular Time

Tags: java, android, notifications, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I am a beginner for Java Coding and is currently coding an Android Project. Right now, I am facing an issue. I want my `application` to auto remove the `notification` at a particular time.

I've managed to dismiss the `notification` after user click on the `notification`. However, at the same time, I also want the `notification` to auto disappear after a specific time if the user did not react to the `notification`.

Please advise me on how should I do it. If possible, please provide me some examples.

Answer (score 1):

You can start a timer for required seconds as soon you call the method to show notification and inside onFinish() of the timer you can add something like this :

```
NotificationManager nMgr = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
nMgr.cancelAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a timer or something like an alarm and when your criteria is fulfilled, cancel it using :

```
 //clear all pending notifications
        String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
        NotificationManager nMgr = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(ns);
        nMgr.cancelAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Timer` for required timing and for remove `Notification` you can use `cancel()`

```
nMgr.cancel(<notification-id>); // here you have to pass your notification id.
```

If you want to remove all notifications just use

```
nMgr.cancelAll();
```

If you want to remove notification after 2 seconds you can use :

```
    Timer timer=new Timer();
    TimerTask task=new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            nMgr.cancel(notification-id);
        }
    };

    timer.schedule(task, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

i suggest use handler method to remove the notification from the notification bar. You can specify the time lenght in miliseconds at handler. this will recalled once only after the entered time.

```
 Handler h = new Handler();
long delayInMilliseconds = 5000;
h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        mNotificationManager.cancel(YourNotificationId);
    }
}, delayInMilliseconds);
```